# Comparing Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks

Let's assume a multilayer perceptron with $l$ layers and $n_i$ neurons at each layer $i=1, \cdots, l$. The number of input neurons $n_1$ and the number of output neurons $n_l$ are fixed. Now I would like to compare different network architectures with each other under the following constraint:

- the number of connections between all neurons is constant
  *or*
- the number of neurons in the network is constant.

I was told to keep the number of neurons constant. But under this constraint I can maximize the number of connections between neurons by keeping only one hidden layer which results in a network of higher capacity (much more weights $w$).

In my opinion the number of connections, and thus the weights should be kept constant while playing around with the network's architecture.

I would like to know which constraint makes more sense?

Answer (score 2):

I think the more general way to look at this is not in terms of "connections," which can be challenging to apply in the case of networks that are not multi-layer perceptrons, but instead in terms of *parameters* (weights and biases).

For example, there is a dramatic difference in the number of parameters in a GRU and LSTM cell. Keeping the number of cells the same implies that the LSTM network has many more parameters than the GRU network, and hence a larger capacity to learn.

Comment: In case of a multilayer perceptron network, what are its parameters? Only the weights and biases?

Comment: @Samuel That's correct. If you've found my answer helpful, please consider up-voting or accepting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to compare, if you want to compares **architectures** under constraints, you can change between **number of hidden layers** or **number of neurons per layer**.

Number of connections between layers are constant depending on number of neurons.